# Building a C# Linq helper

Tags: c#, linq, filter, linq-to-objects

I'm trying to build a utility method using Linq that will help me with a common Linq-to-Objects search.

I have a PropertyTbl object which has a reference to an Address.
I have a `IEnumerable<PropertyTbl>`.
I have written a helper that takes an `IEnumerable<Address>` and some search criteria returns an `IEnumerable<Address>` which when iterated will give me the matching addresses.

However I can't figure out how to plug the two together because although I can do a .Select() on my `IEnumerable<PropertyTbl>` to get the address enumerable I need the result to be `IEnumerable<PropertyTbl>`.

Here's my helper code

```
    public static IEnumerable<Address> BuildAddressWhereClause(IEnumerable<Address> addresses, string value, AddressSearchOptions options)
    {
        string search = value.ToUpper();

        if ((options & AddressSearchOptions.Address1To4) == AddressSearchOptions.Address1To4)
        {
            addresses = addresses.Where(o => o.Address1.ToUpper().Contains(search)
                                             || o.Address2.ToUpper().Contains(search)
                                             || o.Address3.ToUpper().Contains(search)
                                             || o.Address4.ToUpper().Contains(search));
        }

        if ((options & AddressSearchOptions.City) == AddressSearchOptions.City)
        {
            addresses = addresses.Where(o => o.City.ToUpper().Contains(search));
        }

        if ((options & AddressSearchOptions.PostCode) == AddressSearchOptions.PostCode)
        {
            addresses = addresses.Where(o => o.PostCode.ToUpper().Contains(search));
        }

        return addresses;
    }
```

and what I want to do is this.

```
IEnumerable<PropertyTbl> properties = ...;

IEnumerable<PropertyTbl> filteredProperties = <use my address helper somehow>;

// this works but I need the properties as the result not just the addresses
IEnumerable<Address> filteredAddresses = AddressUtils.FilterAddresses(properties.Select(o => o.Address), "1 High Street", ...);
```

I can do what I want by putting the helper code directly into the code where properties are being loaded/filtered but then I can't reuse it.

Any suggestions appreciated.

Comment: @leppie - could you expand on SelectMany?  I've never used that before, maybe that's what I'm missing.

Comment: It's like `from p in properties from a in p.addresses select a` or `properties.SelectMany(p => p.addresses)`. Returns `IEnumerable<Address>`. HTH  :)

Comment: Instead of using `.ToUpper().Contains()`, you can avoid creating the temporary string by using `.IndexOf()` and telling it to do a case-insensitive search: `o.PostCode.IndexOf(search, StringComparison.CurrentCultureIgnoreCase) >= 0`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

An `IEnumerable<PropertyTbl>` is not an `IEnumerable<Address>`, so you need some way of getting to the `Address` field of a `PropertyTable` (unless you change your `BuildAddressWhereClause` to take an `IEnumerable<PropertyTbl>`.

Something like this should do the trick:

```
public static IEnumerable<T> BuildAddressWhereClause<T>(IEnumerable<T> source, string value, AddressSearchOptions options, Func<T, Address> addressExtractor) { 
    string search = value.ToUpper(); 

    if ((options & AddressSearchOptions.Address1To4) == AddressSearchOptions.Address1To4) { 
        source = source.Where(o => addressExtractor(o).Address1.ToUpper().Contains(search) 
                                   || addressExtractor(o).Address2.ToUpper().Contains(search) 
                                   || addressExtractor(o).Address3.ToUpper().Contains(search) 
                                   || addressExtractor(o).Address4.ToUpper().Contains(search)); 
    } 

    if ((options & AddressSearchOptions.City) == AddressSearchOptions.City) { 
        source = source.Where(o => addressExtractor(o).City.ToUpper().Contains(search)); 
    } 

    if ((options & AddressSearchOptions.PostCode) == AddressSearchOptions.PostCode) { 
        source = source.Where(o => addressExtractor(o).PostCode.ToUpper().Contains(search)); 
    } 

    return source; 
}
```

And then you invoke it like

```
IEnumerable<PropertyTbl> properties = ...;      
IEnumerable<PropertyTbl> filteredProperties = AddressUtils.FilterAddresses(properties, "whatever", AddressSearchOptions.Whatever, p => p.Address);
```